Add interactive content from 3rd-party to a CMS website (Elementor / Wix-like)
we're running a website with a CMS at the end of its life-cycle.
Basically, the website features widgets (text, images etc.) we're pulling on the site.
From time to time we're confronted with new requests and elements, especially for campaigns we want to integrate. Basically, these are sliders, elements with pop-ups etc.
I wanted to check with you guys, if we're missing something on our tool kit or if there is another solution we should consider.
In the past we used the following options to simply add interactive elements and areas to our website:

Visme: Just basic interaction options, okay if mobile and desktop look the same
Elfsight: Works, if the requirements fit with one of the existings widgets
Add the elements HTML code directly in the page with additional CSS and JavaScript. This is developed by our developers from the scratch, has the best result but is of course expensive as everything needs to be developed

As you can see, the options we have used in the past always come with so limitations.
Ideally I'm looking for something like Wix or Elementor, where you create the wanted part in some sort of WYSIWYG editor, define interactions and add this part via script or iframe to the designated part of the website. Neither Wix or Elementor in Wordpress is designed to just embed only a specific part created there (IMO).
I'm aware that a solution like this comes also with limitations (SEO, loading time) but I would happy, if you share your thoughts and experiences with me here.
